# Automate word template coloring

Tags: power-automate, powerapps, word-template

In Power Automate through the "populate a template word" connector I am trying to insert data into the precisely my template, as far as inserting the data is concerned, but the problem lies in organizing the template as I can't make sure that the background of some rows changes depending on a value that I find in my array. example:

```
{
    "ResultSets":
        {
            "Table1":[{
                        "col1": "Accessories",
                        "col2":"", 
                        "col3": "",
                        "col4": "",
                        "col5":"",
                        "RankVal": 1       
                    },
                    {
                        "col1": "111111",
                        "col2": "wa-rs-td1",
                        "col3": "use for wall",
                        "col4": "13.16000",
                        "col5": "Mobility",
                        "RankVal": 2
                    }]
        }
}
```

where the value is 1 I would like the entire row of the table to be coloured orange for example VBA doesn't work because it doesn't work in the background so I have to find a way to make it understand, please help me
I tried to use VBA, but without success, I tried to rebuild the array but without success, because power automation is limited in these things, I tried to transfer an Excel table inside the table on the word template, but here too I lost the colour formatting, and if you ask me if I tried to pre-format the template, the answer is yes, but it makes no sense as the item categories are more than one and therefore the values ​​associated with RankValue = 1 are also more than one.   [I would like the result to look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZv8g.png)